# Code Blocks gives wrong solutions while online compiler doesn't

Tags: c, gcc

everyone.

I am using Code Blocks 16.01 , with the compiler GNU GCC . My current OS is 32-bit Windows 7.

I am a newbie to C programming. These days , i have been working on a program that simply output the reversed number of the input positive integer .For example : with input 12345 , output will be 54321.

Here are my codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int Number=0;
    int i=0,j=0;
    //Input
    printf("\nEnter your positive number:\t");
    scanf(" %d",&Number);
    //Force a valid input
    while (Number<0){
        printf("\nInvalid input.");
        printf("\nEnter your positive number:\t");
        scanf(" %d",&Number);
    }
    //Identifying the number of digits
    for (i=1;;i++){
        if((Number/(int)pow(10,i)<1))break;//Dividing for 10 until the result is < 1 then break
    }
    printf("\nYour input number is %d digits long.\n",i);
    //Preparing for the reverse process
    int D=i;
    int NUMBER[D+1];
    int Num1=Number;
    i=D-1;j=0;

    //Extracting the digits from the number
    for(i=D-1;i>=0;i--){
    NUMBER[i]=Num1%10;
    Num1=Num1/10;
    }
    int ReversedDigits[D+1];
    int ReversedNumber=0;

    for(i=0,j=D-1;i<=D-1,j>=0;i++,j--){
        ReversedDigits[i]=NUMBER[j];
        ReversedNumber+=ReversedDigits[i]*(int)pow(10,j);
    }
    printf("\nThe reversed number is %d.\n",ReversedNumber);

}
```

I compiled and ran the program , input 1234 but instead of having 4321 as output, i got 4318 in return (You can check the image included).[The program ran and compiled using Code Blocks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tye5H.png)

I have looked for logical error and couldn't find them anywhere .

Then i copied the code to compile it online . I use the page :https://www.codechef.com/ide to compile my code with compiler C (GCC-4.9.2)
and it gives a perfect output.(You can copy and run my codes on that page to verify ).

So i reached a conclusion that something is wrong with my Code Blocks.

I have re-installed Code Blocks on my laptop but that doesn't help at all . The problem still remained .

Does anyone have any idea of why this happen and how to fix it ? I would greatly appreciate any help there is .

Comment: `i <= D-1, j >= 0` throws out the result of the first comparison. Did you mean `&&` instead of `,`? Also, can you think of how you’d do this without an array? It would make the program much faster and simpler.

Comment: I tended to do it using a string but my teacher has not allowed me to use library string.h ! So i am stuck with this method !

Comment: @Ryan i have just added this to the for loop mistake that you found( without any changes from my original one) : printf("\n %d",ReversedDigits[i]); and it still works out fine, the reversed digits are all correct ! I think that it is not an error there .

Comment: @PhucHuyNguyenPhuong It can be done without using any string or array - Look [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-reverse-digits-of-a-number/).

Comment: The problem is related to pow. Try to print out (int)pow(10,2)...My solution is to use (int)powf(10.0,1.0*j).

Comment: you could force the user to enter a positive number by 1) declaring: `unsigned int number;`  and `scanf( "u", &number );`  However, need to check returned value from `scanf()` which in this scenario must be 1 otherwise an error occurred.

Comment: this statement: if((Number/(int)pow(10,i)<1)) will perform an integer divide, so will lose the fraction values thereby your result could be off by 1.  Suggest. save = 10; multiply (in a loop) save = i * save.  if save > number then done else increment i and loop

Comment: it would have been much easier and much less error prone to read the number as a string, then just reverse the string. finally output the string.

Comment: Thanks all for your help , i have figured out the mistake now !